# Converting array of mutable pointers to mutable references with const generics

Tags: arrays, rust, reference

Suppose that I guarantee (through unspecified means) that I have an array of type `[*mut T; N]` containing `N` **valid and disjoint** mutable pointers, all with lifetime `'a`. How can I convert this to an array of mutable references `[&'a mut T; N]`?

In other words, how can I implement this function?

```
unsafe fn ptrs_to_refs<'a, T, const N: usize>(ptrs: [*mut T; N]) -> [&'a mut T; N] {
    // What goes here?
}
```

I'm not particularly looking for an implementation that uses an allocation step (e.g. using `Vec`).

---

Because `min_const_generics` is [set to stabilize](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/79135) in Rust 1.51, this question is targetting a hypothetical stable Rust that also has `min_const_generics`. I am looking for answers compatible with these requirements, using no other unstable features.

E.g. with the feature [`array_map`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/75243) one can simply

```
unsafe fn ptrs_to_refs<'a, T, const N: usize>(ptrs: [*mut T; N]) -> [&'a mut T; N] {
   arr.map(|ptr| unsafe { &mut *ptr })
}
```

but since that is not set to stabilize by 1.51 (as far as I know) I do not wish to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you would just use [`std::mem::transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.transmute.html) here, as [references and pointers have the same memory layout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#pointers-and-references-layout). Unfortunately, `std::mem::transmute` doesn't work on generic arrays, even when the two types have the same layout. However, you can use `union` to work around this, as [using a `#[repr(C)]` union is analogous to `transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/unions.html#reading-and-writing-union-fields):

```rust
#[repr(C)]
union Transmute<'a, T, const N: usize> {
    ptr_arr: ManuallyDrop<[*mut T; N]>,
    ref_arr: ManuallyDrop<[&'a mut T; N]>,
}

unsafe fn ptrs_to_refs<'a, T, const N: usize>(ptrs: [*mut T; N]) -> [&'a mut T; N] {
    let u = Transmute::<'a, T, N> { ptr_arr: ManuallyDrop::new(ptrs) };
    ManuallyDrop::into_inner(u.ref_arr)
}
```

You can also use [`std::mem::transmute_copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.transmute_copy.html), which effectively does the same here:

```rust
unsafe fn ptrs_to_refs<'a, T, const N: usize>(ptrs: [*mut T; N]) -> [&'a mut T; N] {
    std::mem::transmute_copy(&ptrs)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::mem::transmute` would be where I'd reach for first, but that doesn't currently work; see [Const generics: Generic array transmutes do not work #61956](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/61956) for full details.

In the meantime, you can [use a union](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/61956#issuecomment-752045990) as a workaround, since pointers and references [have the same layout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.49.0/reference/type-layout.html#pointers-and-references-layout):

```rust
use core::mem::ManuallyDrop;

unsafe fn ptrs_to_refs<'a, T, const N: usize>(ptrs: [*mut T; N]) -> [&'a mut T; N] {
    union X<'a, T, const N: usize> {
        a_raw: ManuallyDrop<[*mut T; N]>,
        a_ref: ManuallyDrop<[&'a mut T; N]>,
    }

    let a_raw = ManuallyDrop::new(ptrs);
    let x = X { a_raw };
    ManuallyDrop::into_inner(x.a_ref)
}
```

You should also be able to use [`transmute_copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute_copy.html) to the same effect:

```rust
unsafe fn ptrs_to_refs<'a, T, const N: usize>(ptrs: [*mut T; N]) -> [&'a mut T; N] {
    std::mem::transmute_copy(&ptrs)
}
```

Comment: Is transmuting a pointer to a reference (assuming that the pointer is valid and the result doesn't alias with another reference) guaranteed to be safe? My current idea was to reborrow into a `MaybeUninit` array and then `transmute_copy` the `MaybeUninit` away (which is guaranteed to be safe).

Comment: And I believe that if this answer is correct and it *is* safe to transmute directly between the arrays, simply replacing the entire body with `std::mem::transmute_copy(&ptrs)` would work.

Comment: @orlp it looks like [Frxstrem's answer links to the reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65533695/155423) that says the layouts are the same, which is what makes the transmute OK. I thought I tried `transmute_copy` first and it failed, but I do see that working now...

Comment: Does 'same layout' imply that the bit representation is also the same if they point to the same object? What about the alignment? The alignment is also relevant since we're considering arrays here.

Comment: @orlp yes, as I read it it will have the same alignment and padding.

Answer (score 2):

Adapting an example from the [`MaybeUninit` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#initializing-an-array-element-by-element):

```
unsafe fn ptrs_to_refs<'a, T, const N: usize>(ptrs: [*mut T; N]) -> [&'a mut T; N] {
    // Create an uninitialized array of `MaybeUninit`. The `assume_init` is
    // safe because the type we are claiming to have initialized here is a
    // bunch of `MaybeUninit`s, which do not require initialization.
    let mut refs: [MaybeUninit<&'a mut T>; N] = MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init();
    
    // Dropping a `MaybeUninit` does nothing. Thus using raw pointer
    // assignment instead of `ptr::write` does not cause the old
    // uninitialized value to be dropped.
    for i in 0..N {
        refs[i] = MaybeUninit::new(&mut *ptrs[i]);
    }
    
    std::mem::transmute_copy::<_, [&'a mut T; N]>(&refs)
}
```

This answer does not rely on whether it's safe to transmute `[*mut T; N]` to `[&mut T; N]`, but only on `MaybeUninit<T>` to `T` after properly initializing.

Comment: I thought about mentioning this, but that loop just made me so sad. Could do `for (a, b) in refs.zip(ptrs) { *a = b }`.

Comment: @Shepmaster That'd require `array_zip` which isn't stable. Plus this way I know for sure there's not any extra magical copies/moves/drops going on that'd violate safety. There is a time for idiomatic Rust but I'll stick to stuff I can 100% immediately see is safe in these bowels of the beast.

Comment: [what am I missing?](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c3c07188d3c0de69afe34a6d6461ee9b)

Comment: @Shepmaster That'd work but I still disagree that it's more readable.